# Building VTK in Visual studio 2008 Windows 64 bit

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vtk

I built and configured VTK using cmake in visual studio according to the link below:

> http://vtkblog.blogspot.com/2007/04/install-build-vtk-from-source-in-visual.html

But I get linking errors as below:

> 1>vtk_minimal.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera * __cdecl vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera::New(void)" (?New@vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera@@SAPAV1@XZ) referenced in function _main
>   1>vtk_minimal.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall vtkRenderWindowInteractor::SetRenderWindow(class vtkRenderWindow *)" (?SetRenderWindow@vtkRenderWindowInteractor@@QAEXPAVvtkRenderWindow@@@Z) referenced in function _main
>   1>vtk_minimal.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkRenderWindowInteractor * __cdecl vtkRenderWindowInteractor::New(void)" (?New@vtkRenderWindowInteractor@@SAPAV1@XZ) referenced in function _main
>   1>vtk_minimal.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkRenderWindow * __cdecl vtkRenderWindow::New(void)" (?New@vtkRenderWindow@@SAPAV1@XZ) referenced in function _main
>   1>vtk_minimal.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall vtkRenderer::AddActor(class vtkProp *)" (?AddActor@vtkRenderer@@QAEXPAVvtkProp@@@Z) referenced in function _main
>   1>vtk_minimal.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkRenderer * __cdecl vtkRenderer::New(void)" (?New@vtkRenderer@@SAPAV1@XZ) referenced in function _main
>   1>vtk_minimal.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkActor * __cdecl vtkActor::New(void)" (?New@vtkActor@@SAPAV1@XZ) referenced in function _main
>   1>vtk_minimal.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkPolyDataMapper * __cdecl vtkPolyDataMapper::New(void)" (?New@vtkPolyDataMapper@@SAPAV1@XZ) referenced in function _main
>   1>vtk_minimal.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkConeSource * __cdecl vtkConeSource::New(void)" (?New@vtkConeSource@@SAPAV1@XZ) referenced in function _main
>   1>vtk_minimal.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class vtkAlgorithmOutput * __thiscall vtkAlgorithm::GetOutputPort(int)" (?GetOutputPort@vtkAlgorithm@@QAEPAVvtkAlgorithmOutput@@H@Z) referenced in function "public: class vtkAlgorithmOutput * __thiscall vtkAlgorithm::GetOutputPort(void)" (?GetOutputPort@vtkAlgorithm@@QAEPAVvtkAlgorithmOutput@@XZ)
>   1>Debug/../bin/vtk_minimal_d.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals

Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure that you specified the VTK libraries in the Linker -> Input -> "Additional Dependencies" property?

Comment: I have included vtk  in library and include sections in Tools->options->VC++ directories. How do I add it to Additional dependancies? Do I have to add all the libs?

Comment: You have to tell the linker where to find the definitions of the functions that you're calling. I told you where to find the setting. Look in your project's Properties.

Comment: Thanks Cody Gray. I added all the libs, but stil getting the error. :(

Comment: Check your calling conventions then. Make sure that you're not compiling the project with the `/Gz` switch or explicitly specifying a different calling convention for the functions provided by the library. The error message that you posted appears to indicate that the functions are declared `__cdecl`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using CMake to configure VTK before building. Here are some instructions: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Building/Windows